# Script with Skype4py is failing on python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, x11, skype4py

I am running my script on python2.7 and receivng this kind of issue:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
Major opcode of failed request:  25 (X_SendEvent)
Resource id in failed request:  0x300000f
Serial number of failed request:  14
Current serial number in output stream:  14
```

I tried to google it, but with no success. The point is that it worked fine 2 days ago (on Friday), but now I can't figure it out. 
I am using skype 4.3.0.37, working on Elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya (64 bit) based on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
client = Skype(Transport='x11')
client.Attach() 
user = 'myskype'
message = report_list
client.SendMessage(user, message)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess it it because of Transport, but I am not sure. If I left it like: client = Skype()

I receive this error:
raise SkypeAPIError('Skype attach timeout')
Skype4Py.errors.SkypeAPIError: Skype attach timeout

Comment: So it seems problem is definitely in the X11. Can anyone give me alternative of it?

Comment: I tried dbus transport but it failed too. It seems there are only 2 transport types for skype4py.